# How to get all arguments from following function in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, printf, variadic-functions

following is the implementation of my method

```
static VALUE myMethod(VALUE self, VALUE exc, const char* fmt, ...) { 
   // Need to get all the arguments passed to this function and print it 
}
```

function is called as follows:

```
myMethod(exception, ""Exception message: %s, Exception object %d",
          "Hi from Exception", 100);
```

Can you provide the code for `myMethod()` that will access all the arguments and print them out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and what specific problems you are facing.

Answer (score 4):

The va_start and va_arg macro's are used to get the variable arguments in a function.
An example can be found on the Microsoft site: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb57fad8(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb57fad8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

In your case it's a bit trickier, since you need to parse the format string to exactly know how many arguments should be given and of which type they are.  Luckily, the CRT contains a function for that.  The vfprintf function can be given a va_list (which you get from va_start).  vfprintf will use this one to process all the extra arguments.  See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/vfprintf/ for an example.

Comment: Additional information about printing functions here: http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=3&topic=vsnprintf These are  standardized and exist in the Microsoft environment as well.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use vsnprintf().

Sample code:

```
char buf[256];
va_list args;

va_start(args, fmt);

if(vsnprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), fmt, args) > 0)
  fputs(buf, stderr);

va_end(args);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use va_start and va_arg macros to get the arguments.
You can take a look at this - it has some examples.

http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=17592